# Kryonet won't connect from android

Tags: java, android, kryonet

I have created a client and a server, which both work fine and have no trouble connecting. Now I would like to be able to connect from my android phone to the server. I have imported the kryonet library and copy-pasted the client code into a new android project. The code gave me some errors, but I fixed those. When I tried testing my app, it didn't give me any errors, but my server wasn't getting any connections either. I looked a bit in the LogCat logs, and found out it keeps sticking at "Connecting..". I am totally stuck. This is my android code:

```
public void openSocket(View view){
    Log.i(TAG, "test1");
    EditText portText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
    String parts[] = portText.getText().toString().split(":");
    partIP = parts[0];
    String partPort = parts[1];
    port = Integer.parseInt(partPort);

    try {
        client = new Client();
        client.start();
        register();
        pHandler = new PacketHandler();
        connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        pHandler.checkException(e);
    }
}
public static void register() {
    client.getKryo().register(Packet.class);
    client.getKryo().register(Packet1Connected.class);
    client.getKryo().register(String.class);
    client.getKryo().register(String[].class);
    client.getKryo().register(Object[].class);
}
public static void connect() {
    try {
        String IP = "*MY IP*:25565";
        String[] Ip = IP.split(":");
        String ipFinal = Ip[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(Ip[1]);

        client.connect(5000, ipFinal, port, port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.");
        connect();
    }

    Packet1Connected packet = new Packet1Connected();
    packet.id = "Android";

    client.sendTCP(packet);
}
```

And this is my normal client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            client = new Client();
            client.start();
            register();
            pHandler = new PacketHandler();
            new Main();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pHandler.checkException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void register() {
        client.getKryo().register(Packet.class);
        client.getKryo().register(Packet1Connected.class);
        client.getKryo().register(String.class);
        client.getKryo().register(String[].class);
        client.getKryo().register(Object[].class);
    }

    public Main() {
        try {
            connect();
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pHandler.checkException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void connect() {
        try {
            String IP = "*MY IP*:25565";

            String[] Ip = IP.split(":");
            String ipFinal = Ip[0];
            int port = Integer.parseInt(Ip[1]);

            client.connect(5000, ipFinal, port, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Trying to connect.");
            connect();
        }

        Packet1Connected packet = new Packet1Connected();
        packet.id = System.getProperty("user.name");

        client.sendTCP(packet);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                if (!client.isConnected()) 
                    connect();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                pHandler.checkException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So this:

```
    client.connect(5000, ipFinal, port, port);
```

is the line it gets stuck on, on android. The normal client just connects normally.

Now my question is, is there something wrong with my android code, or is it just the device, or wifi connection?

If it helps, I tried testing it on my samsung galaxy nexus, which is rooted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but I had problems connecting at the default high port, but it worked on 2300 and 2301.

Comment: I found that being usb debug connected to Eclipse caused connection problems for Kryonet.